# how to convert javaScript validation script to jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have the following javascript form validation code. How do i convert the it to jQuery?

```
if(forms.fname.value == "") { 
alert("You have not entered your First Name")
    forms.fname.style.borderColor = "#f00"; 
    forms.fname.focus(); 
    return false; 
}
if(!forms.fname.value.match (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) ) { 
alert("Please enter only character in this field") 
    forms.fname.style.borderColor = "#f00"; 
    forms.fname.focus(); 
    return false; 
}
else {
    forms.fname.style.borderColor = "#000";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("input[name=fname]").val() == "") {
    alert ("error, fill name");
    $("#formid").css("border","1px solid red");
    return false;
} else {
    $("#formid").focus();

}
```

Try continiuing the solution. basically, jquery is a javascript library which wrote completely in javascript and the combination is a natural result.

Comment: but how di i check that only text is inputted in the input?

Comment: thanks for your answer but the script does not work.